# List is not rendering

Tags: arrays, reactjs

The error I get:

> Objects are not valid as a React child, If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

here res is a json which has nested arrays so i have used _.foreach for extracting it and state is successfully updating but problem lies in displaying it

```
    class ViewExchange extends React.Component{ 
      state={list:[],refresh:false}
      componentWillMount(props){
    
        if(_.isEmpty(Cookies.get())){
         this.props.history.push("/signup")
        }
        else{

        let platform = Cookies.get('platform')
 
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/user/viewexchange',{platform})
        .then(res=>{
 
          this.setState({list:res.data})
          _.forEach(this.state.list,(value)=>{
            _.forEach(value.url,(e)=>this.setState({list:[e]}))
            })
        })
        }
      }

        renderList=()=>{
          console.log("in method")
        return this.state.list.map((item,key)=>{
        
          return <div key={key}>{item}</div>
        })
        }
    
     render(){

      return (
        <div>
          {this.renderList()}
        </div>
    );
      }
}
export default withRouter(ViewExchange);
```

Comment: what do you have in `this.state.list`? quite hard to help you with limited info...

Comment: Also provide the content of `this.state.list`

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly comes when you try to show some content in jsx which is not a valid object key ( instead is an object itself ). In your case it will be like:

```
return this.state.list.map((item,key)=>{ return <div key={key}>{item.index}</dv> });  // instead of item, you have to use item.index which is an existing key of object
```

Here `item.index` is the index which you want to show from the object and don't forget to provide the `key`, in absence of `key` it will show a warning also performance is compromised.